# set only zero flag in assembly, not affecting other flags

Tags: x86, eflags

I need to set the zero flag in assembly but it shouldn't change any other flags.
so I was thinking to do pushf, pop it to eax but I have no idea how to give the flag reg it's new value.
all I can think of :

```
pushf
pop eax,
or eax , 000..1..00 // set the location of zf to 1
```

and from here I have no idea what to do.

Comment: There's a `popf` instruction.

Comment: but it will restore the original value of the register, no?

Comment: It will pop whatever is on the stack into the flags register.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution not involving any other register:

```
pushf
or dword [esp],64  ;bit[6] has ZF
popf
```